# Why DOMParser doesn't use the customElements registered?

Tags: javascript, element, domparser, custom-element

When registering customElements and parsing html via the DOMParser with customElements in it, they aren't constructed, they only get constructed when they get appended into the main document.

I can't check if they instanceof an element because of that.

Is there a way to force the DOMParser to use and call the customElements constructor ?

I don't really want to parse the html with the DOMParser and have to create a copy with document.createElement (using document.createElement actually calls the customElement constructor even if not appended)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `document.importNode(_elem)` that is actually capable of getting the element constructed before appending it

Answer (score 0):

In this document: https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-upgrades-examples

It explains:

**Note that upgrades only apply to elements in the document tree. (Formally, elements that are connected.) An element that is not inserted into a document will stay un-upgraded.**

To extend this, an element can only be upgraded after two things happen:

1) The element must be defined.
2) The element must exist in the document tree.